# Can you store the position attribute in an attribute number other than 0

Tags: c++, opengl

In OpenGL, I always see that the position attribute is always placed at attribute 0. Is it possible for the position attribute to be at number 1? Why is the position attribute always at attribute 0?

Answer (score 4):

Outside of the now-removed `gl_Vertex` built-in attribute, there is no such thing as a "position attribute." GLSL has *no idea* which attribute corresponds to a "position". They're all just numbers to your vertex shader; they only gain meaning when you assign something to `gl_Position`.

Which is a vertex shader *output*. How you generate the value for that output is none of GLSL's business.

That having been said, older versions of OpenGL did anoint attribute 0 with special powers. But these were mainly vestigial elements from fixed-function `glBegin/End`-style programming, and they were not required to have the meaning "position". The only special status it had was that you had to put *something* there. That is, you couldn't not use attribute 0.

But again, that's long-since been removed from OpenGL. Nowadays, people put a "position" there merely by habit.